# net::ERR_ABORTED 401 (Unauthorized). How do I fix this react error?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api, unauthorized

I am trying to create very simple react app that can create POST requests. The API that I am trying to reach is password protected so I tried having Authorization header in post request but couldn't get it working. Any help would be appreciated.

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import './App.css'; 
class App extends Component{
      async postData(){
          try {
            let result = await fetch('https://u0l8meat1b-u0dl1g7crl-connect.us0-aws.organization.io/gateways/simplestoragedev/',{
             method : 'POST',
            mode: 'no-cors',
             headers: {
           'Authorization' : 'Basic dTB2eHRtNjZlcjpwUTcxalVtZFZ1Sm9BE0hHVXREaDFRajF5cjBCbGVEY25BWjBMNkdnREhJCg',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
             x : "2"
        })
      })
      console.log('Result:' + result)
    }catch (e){
      console.log(e);
    }
  }
render(){
  return (
    <div className = "App">
        <button onClick = { () => this.postData()}>Press</button>
    </div>
  );
}
}
```

Comment: Try it with curl first. I think you put the wrong header value.

Comment: I’m not sure if that’s your real authentication in the code snippet, and if it is you should generate a new one if possible.

Comment: I am getting same issue, do we get any solution to that